# Calculating the annulus of a sphere with a differential change in theta

Tags: geometry, triangles, spherical-coordinates, spheres

Consider the following object:

[image]

I want to calculate the area of the annulus. The annulus is within the 
region of $$ \theta    $$ and $$ \theta + d\theta   $$

The answer of the area of the annulus is apparently
$$ 2\pi sin(\theta)d\theta $$ but I am unsure why this is.
Any explanation would be useful

Comment: Spherical coordinates are the way to go. Once you understand the definition you will be able to set up the integral and evaluate it quickly.

Answer (score 3):

If you cut the annulus you get a rectangular ribbon, with length $2\pi\sin\theta$ and height $d\theta$. Its area is then $2\pi\sin\theta d\theta$.

[image]